# Crash report - Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded

Tags: ios, swift

I got this crash report, and I don't know how to read it -

```
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded, Arg[2] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded, Arg[3] = Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded, Arg[4] = Owned To Guaranteed> of LoginViewController.(doneButtonPressed (Swift.AnyObject) -> ()).(closure #1) (LoginViewController.swift:60)
```

Basicity it's happens at function A that calls to function B with a completion handler and func B calls and passes that completion handler to function C.

What is all this "Owned To Guaranteed and Exploded" ?
Is it because I'm trying to access a nil object? or maybe it's related to the fact that I'm passing the completion handler and I need to use @escaping (don't think so because I'm passing it as optional)

Comment: Have you tried adding the `@escaping` annotation?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it so that way I asked what can cause it. My guess is that I tried to access a nil object. If I'm wrong I'll also try the @escaping